# Enlarging a Very Small Image Clearly

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, scale

I would like to (clearly) enlarge a very small image.

However, when I use a typical approach by adjusting the scaling factor, I get a fuzzy image.

For example, consider

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{tous_les_jours.png}\\[35pt]
\includegraphics[scale=8]{tous_les_jours.png}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: Is there an alternative approach I use to enlarge the very small image so that a clear picture results?

Thank you.

Comment: go back to the orginal source (if there is one), a png is not scalable it is a fixed number of pixels, so all you can do is make the pixels bigger, so the image looks blocky, you can not create information that is not there

Comment: if you use a graphics editor it may be possible to use heuristics or even human creative input to synthesise a higher resolution image to include.

Comment: It will seem less blocky is you use the `interpolate=true` option of `\includegraphics{...}`, but you can’t get around the fact that your image is of low resolution.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you; `interpoloate=true` seems to help a bit. You're right about the low resolution.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your helpful comments. Incidentally, based on something I found on this site, I thought that converting the png image to an eps image might help a little, but there seems to be no difference.

Comment: You could open it in inkscape and run a vector trace to try to turn it from a raster graphic to a vector graphic, but don't count on it "clearly" still saying "tous les jours" afterwards.

Comment: @mlchristians the file format is just a detail, pdflatex is doing essentially the same conversion anyway to include the image in pdf. If you scale up your Monet, the artist doesn't emerge and paint a large canvas, you just get big dots.

Comment: @frabjous Many thanks for the Inkscape suggestion.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see.